# Can Elliptic Curve Cryptography be used as a block ciper?

Tags: encryption, embedded, elliptic-curve

I am trying to use asymmetric encryption to encrypt firmware. The bootloader will decrypt and update the flash. This is on a embedded device with 32 bit CPU executing at 60MHz.

I want to use ECC due to its varies advantages. I am new to encryption and my understanding os ECC as implemented in ECIES is to use ECC for the key generation and use AES for actual data encryption. Due to code and ram size, I cannot support multiple encryption algorithms.

Is there a implementation of ECC that can be used just like AES. All I am looking for is to use a "Private key" to encrypt firmware and the bootloader uses "Public Key" to decrypt it.

Thanks.

Comment: AES can be implemented with an extremely small footprint.  I'd be surprised that you can fit ECC but not AES.

Comment: That's way more CPU power and MHz than I have got to my disposal. Besides that, do you have that little flash? Because you could share the RAM crypto buffers as long as you don't mix cryptographic primitives and/or use multi-threading. Otherwise try one of the newer stream ciphers with a small footprint.

Comment: By the way, why do you need to *encrypt* the firmware? Is signature validation not enough?

Comment: @owlstead, it's common to encrypt firmware.  It prevents competitors and hackers from reverse engineering easily.

Comment: @TJD I can definitely fit AES. I want to use asymmetric encryption so that the key that resides on bootloader can only be used for decryption.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with asymmetric encryption + signing, not easily anyway. Maybe you could do this symmetrically, but then you would have to encrypt per device. Feasible?

Comment: 1) Using a Symmetric Block or Stream encryption algorithm means that you're going to have the ability for someone to figure out the key and produce binaries.  Locking them out to not see is of import but keeping people from producing unsupported binaries is moreso.
2) libcurve *might* fit into this space.  It's probably a bit more compute intensive than AES, but something along the lines there should be usable.  If not you might reach for lattice function encryption (though I think that might be too memory hungry for you...)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that you completely understand what ECIES consists of:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Encryption_Scheme

That's quite a bit of work, and it requires a whole lot of primitives, including at least one symmetric primitive, it seems to me. That might as well be AES.

Comment: ECIES is quite a lot of work and I dont need all that functionality. 

I am looking for an encryption scheme that is as strong as AES but uses separate (private/public) keys to encrypt/ decrypt

Comment: @Sabdeep: every asymmetric encryption scheme uses a symmetric cipher to actually encrypt the data. The only situation where you could not be doing this, is when you're encrypting very little data: less than 50 bytes. And even then it's probably not a good idea, because asymmetric encryption tends to leak private key info if the encrypted data isn't random.

Comment: @HubertKario to expand on your explanation: you need random padding to be secure. Normally this is accomplished by a padding mode that is applied before the encryption primitive takes place. Examples are those specified by PKCS#1 v1.5 & OAEP for RSA and ECIES for EC. So basically the maximum amount of plain text you can encrypt is the ciphertext - overhead - padding. As EC has short keys, you won't have much space left for your plain text. Furthermore, each block of plain text requires a modulo exponentiation, which is very costly regarding CPU.

Comment: @owlstead: yes, you're right. I don't remember where I've read it, but AFAICR if you encrypt the same data (or encrypted data has some structure) over and over again then there are attacks to recover single bits of private key info. All in all, not using hybrid encryption is just not worth the problems raw asymmetric encryption brings.

Comment: @HubertKario for EC, encrypting two different values without random completely recovers *all* of the private key bytes, as the Chaos Computer Club showed with one of the signing keys of Sony (they used a [constant random](http://xkcd.com/221/)).

Comment: @HubertKario After further reading and I understand that asymmetric encryption is used to safeguard / generate a key for the symmetric encryption for large blocks of data.

Considering the processing resources, I am considering symmetric encryption for my needs.

Comment: @Sandeep: yes, you understand correctly, just remember that if you're using only symmetric encryption, then it takes only one person to disassemble the software and look for key to defeat the whole process. Both AES and ECC were designed/chosen *specifically* for usability in highly constrained environments, so that they could be implemented on smart cards. A 60MHz 32bit CPU probably has more cache than some of those cards whole memory...

Answer (score 2):

Let's start from the last sentence of the question:

> All I am looking for is to use a "Private key" to encrypt firmware and the bootloader uses "Public Key" to decrypt it.

There's some confusion in terminology here. Private keys are used to decrypt (or sign) and public keys are used to encrypt (or verify). If I understand correctly, what you want is for the bootloader to verify a signature on the firmware so that only a firmware that was properly signed by yourself will be accepted by the bootloader.

There are various asymmetric signature schemes which can be used for this purpose, including some which are based on eliptic curve cryptography. For example you could use the OpenSSL implementation of ECDSA (see http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/ecdsa.html).

I'm afraid there's not enough information in the question to properly choose the best signature scheme (and possibly an encryption scheme as well if there is a need to keep the firmware secret). In any case, good cryptography is not enough to make a system secure and other considerations such as secure implementation are no less important.

If this is is something that is important for you to protect and that you are worried that hackers may try to break, I would strongly advise procuring the services of a security professional. Using cryptography correctly is a very tricky business that requires a full understanding of the system - otherwise you may find yourself in a situation like [this](http://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/download/attachments/2426/kurios119.jpg)

Comment: I apologize for misusing terminology(I am new to cryptology). My objective was to keep the firmware secret and less concerned of bootloader accepting only signed code.

My work is a preliminary study and will definitely looked over by security professionals. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: If your "objective is to keep the firmware secret" then there is no reason to use an asymmetric scheme for this and you should simply use AES. In this case the prime security concern is how to best protect the firmware decryption key on the device. This depends on the device's capabilities and if it can store any secrets.

Comment: The [image](http://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/download/attachments/2426/kurios119.jpg) you linked is the definitively correct description of most security scheme  !

Comment: And, again, people *COMPLETELY* miss the need here.  You need to keep it secret from your basic low piker, but you also need signing, etc. to keep someone from being able to submit invalid/altered binaries from a customer support perspective.

AES, by itself, does NOT do this.  Worse, the key is on the target and if an attacker gets it, they can submit their own stuff to the target- which is something that an embedded vendor *DOES NOT WANT HAPPENING*, mainly for support reasons.

Signature systems by themselves do not do this.

Comment: In the end, if you can find a way to keep the low pikers out (A determined attacker will pretty much circumvent anything you do- in order to use it, it's got to be undoable on target, period) and effectively sign things this is a win.  Seriously, folks, if you think AES is a good thing by itself in this application or if you think a signing system is, you need to refrain from answering in comments or in the answers...you don't understand the problem domain *AT ALL*.

Answer (score 2):

If you look for "authentication" you have to use asymmetric algorithm like EC, this usually done because if the user or process want to update the "firmware" he should identify him self to the bootloader  by his "signature" to check who request this update.

After that is done, the bootloader will load the symmetric key from a secure memory to decrypt what you want to do.

So, you have a symmetric key for encryption (AES), and asymmetric two keys for authentication (=Who are you?).

Note: there is no advantages of EC on 32 bit CPU executing at 60MHz for Encryption, unless your application need asymmetric for Encryption NOT authentication, this happen due to line between the user and bootloader is not secure.

Therefore, you could use bootloader's "public key" to encrypt firmware and the bootloader uses its "private Key" to decrypt it, however, the implementation cost a lot due to the high computing for asymmetric algorithm.

Look for "lightweight cryptography", it is typical for your application.